# PHP - SPL file object returning null on seek

Tags: php, file, csv, spl

Alright, I am using SPL file object with a+ mode. The data apends correctly but I want to validate the last row of that data by grabbing it from the file again. The data is CSV format, it works for the first line in the file and apends the 2 line correctly. But when seeking the 2nd line it returns NULL.

```
<?php 
$handle = new SplFileObject("filePath here","a+");
$handle->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

// write using fputcsv
$status = $handle->fputcsv($data,',');
$status = $handle->fputcsv($data,',');
$handle->seek(1);
$fields = $handle->fgetcsv(',');
$fields2 = $handle->current();
```

// Both fields and fields2 return NULL

There would be two lines worth of data in the file. Please help

Comment: Code looks alright to me check if data is empty.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46569, this maybe a environment bug.